# Zsh shift selection

Tags: shell, zsh, copy-paste

How to use shift to select part of the commandline (like in many text editors) ?

Comment: Shells typically don't have this functionality. If it were available, it might be more likely to be provided by the terminal instead, but I'm not familiar with any that do.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Surprisingly I got the same kind of comments on SO. It is just wrong. Zsh implements selection in ZLE (with marks though). And in fact command line editing has almost nothing to do with the terminal...

Comment: You asked about using shift. You didn't ask how text could be selected generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to

1. define new widgets that activate marking on shifted motion keys,
2. redefine all action widgets to operate on the region (if there is one), and
3. redefine all the default motion widgets to deactivate marking.

Here's a proof of concept (for `xterm`), working for:

- `Shift-Left` and `Shift-Right`: start selecting to the left/right, respectively,
- `Left`, `Right`: cancel selecting and move left/right, respectively,
- `Delete`: delete selection if there is one, otherwise character under the cursor.

The usual disclaimers apply (there may be other and better ways, your cat may eat your toaster, etc.).

```
bindkey -e

function zle-line-init {
    marking=0
}
zle -N zle-line-init

function select-char-right {
    if (( $marking != 1 )) 
    then
        marking=1
        zle set-mark-command
    fi
    zle .forward-char
}
zle -N select-char-right

function select-char-left {
    if (( $marking != 1 )) 
    then
        marking=1
        zle set-mark-command
    fi
    zle .backward-char
}
zle -N select-char-left

function forward-char {
    if (( $marking == 1 ))
    then
        marking=0
        NUMERIC=-1 zle set-mark-command
    fi
    zle .forward-char
}
zle -N forward-char

function backward-char {
    if (( $marking == 1 ))
    then
        marking=0
        NUMERIC=-1 zle set-mark-command
    fi
    zle .backward-char
}
zle -N backward-char

function delete-char {
    if (( $marking == 1 ))
    then
        zle kill-region
        marking=0
    else
        zle .delete-char
    fi
}
zle -N delete-char

bindkey '^[[1;2D' select-char-left   # assuming xterm
bindkey '^[[1;2C' select-char-right  # assuming xterm
```

Comment: It makes a nice example of zle customization. Not so common on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) users.

This is combination of other authors answers with respect to them, modified to work in WSL with [Window Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). Behaviour as in standard [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-5.1): ctrl+shift+arrows select, ctrl+x,c,v,a etc. Even  though this is duplicate of [Zsh zle shift selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407916/zsh-zle-shift-selection)

```
# zsh-shift-select https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899296
r-delregion() {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)) then
     zle kill-region
  else
    local widget_name=$1
    shift
    zle $widget_name -- $@
  fi
}
r-deselect() {
  ((REGION_ACTIVE = 0))
  local widget_name=$1
  shift
  zle $widget_name -- $@
}
r-select() {
  ((REGION_ACTIVE)) || zle set-mark-command
  local widget_name=$1
  shift
  zle $widget_name -- $@
}
for key     kcap   seq        mode   widget (
    sleft   kLFT   $'\e[1;2D' select   backward-char
    sright  kRIT   $'\e[1;2C' select   forward-char
    sup     kri    $'\e[1;2A' select   up-line-or-history
    sdown   kind   $'\e[1;2B' select   down-line-or-history
    send    kEND   $'\E[1;2F' select   end-of-line
    send2   x      $'\E[4;2~' select   end-of-line
    shome   kHOM   $'\E[1;2H' select   beginning-of-line
    shome2  x      $'\E[1;2~' select   beginning-of-line
    left    kcub1  $'\EOD'    deselect backward-char
    right   kcuf1  $'\EOC'    deselect forward-char
    end     kend   $'\EOF'    deselect end-of-line
    end2    x      $'\E4~'    deselect end-of-line
    home    khome  $'\EOH'    deselect beginning-of-line
    home2   x      $'\E1~'    deselect beginning-of-line
    csleft  x      $'\E[1;6D' select   backward-word
    csright x      $'\E[1;6C' select   forward-word
    csend   x      $'\E[1;6F' select   end-of-line
    cshome  x      $'\E[1;6H' select   beginning-of-line
    cleft   x      $'\E[1;5D' deselect backward-word
    cright  x      $'\E[1;5C' deselect forward-word
    del     kdch1   $'\E[3~'  delregion delete-char
    bs      x       $'^?'     delregion backward-delete-char
  ) {
  eval "key-$key() {
    r-$mode $widget \$@
  }"
  zle -N key-$key
  bindkey ${terminfo[$kcap]-$seq} key-$key
}
# Fix zsh-autosuggestions https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899296
export ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS=(
  key-right
)
# ctrl+x,c,v https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634916/424080
function zle-clipboard-cut {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)); then
    zle copy-region-as-kill
    print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | clip.exe
    zle kill-region
  fi
}
zle -N zle-clipboard-cut
function zle-clipboard-copy {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)); then
    zle copy-region-as-kill
    print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | clip.exe
  else
    zle send-break
  fi
}
zle -N zle-clipboard-copy
function zle-clipboard-paste {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)); then
    zle kill-region
  fi
  LBUFFER+="$(cat clip.exe)"
}
zle -N zle-clipboard-paste
function zle-pre-cmd {
  stty intr "^@"
}
precmd_functions=("zle-pre-cmd" ${precmd_functions[@]})
function zle-pre-exec {
  stty intr "^C"
}
preexec_functions=("zle-pre-exec" ${preexec_functions[@]})
for key     kcap    seq           widget              arg (
    cx      _       $'^X'         zle-clipboard-cut   _
    cc      _       $'^C'         zle-clipboard-copy  _
    cv      _       $'^V'         zle-clipboard-paste _
) {
  if [ "${arg}" = "_" ]; then
    eval "key-$key() {
      zle $widget
    }"
  else
    eval "key-$key() {
      zle-$widget $arg \$@
    }"
  fi
  zle -N key-$key
  bindkey ${terminfo[$kcap]-$seq} key-$key
}
# Select entire prompt https://stackoverflow.com/a/68987551/13658418
function widget::select-all() {
  local buflen=$(echo -n "$BUFFER" | wc -m | bc)
  CURSOR=$buflen  
  zle set-mark-command
  while [[ $CURSOR > 0 ]]; do
    zle beginning-of-line
  done
}
zle -N widget::select-all
bindkey '^a' widget::select-all
```

Tested on WSL2 "Linux 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2" with Windows Terminal "1.15.3466.0".